# Rails app render external API json response in view after page load with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, salesforce

I have a rails application that has several pages that must pull information from an external API (salesforce API). I have been successfully pulling data through the API, however I would like to provide a better experience to my users and load the view first, then make the API call and load the API response with Ajax.
I have two applicable routes. The first route loads the view and the second route makes the API request

**routes.rb**

```
get 'pending_loans', to: 'lender_account#pending_loans'
get 'pull_pending_loans', to: 'lender_account#pull_pending_loans'
```

The corresponding controller actions look like:

**lender_account_controller.rb**

```
def pull_pending_loans
  @user = current_user
  if @user.activated?
    client = Restforce.new
    @account = client.find('Account', @user.salesforce_id, 'Id')
    pending_query = "select Loan__r.Business_Name__r.Name, Loan__r.Id, Loan__r.Name, Loan__r.Loan_Risk__c, Interest_Rate__c, Amount_Lent__c, Status__c, Loan__r.Time_Left_on_Listing__c, Loan__r.Funded__c from Loan_Part__c where Account__c ='%s' AND Status__c = 'Pledge'" % @account.Id.to_s
    @pendingloanparts = client.query(pending_query)
  end
  render :json => @pendingloanparts
end 

def pending_loans
  @user = current_user
end
```

In my view I have the following:
**pending_loans.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({
    url: "/pull_pending_loans",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      $("#pending_loans").append(html);
    }
  });
</script>

<div class="profile container content">
  <div class="row">
    <%= render 'lenders/sidebar' %> 
      <!-- Begin Content -->
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="profile-body">
            <!-- Pending Loans -->
              <div class="panel panel-purple margin-bottom-40" id="small">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Pending Loans</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover" id="pendingloanlist">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Company</th>
                      <th>Loan Title</th>
                      <th>Risk</th>
                      <th>Rate</th>
                      <th>Amount</th>
                      <th>% Funded</th>
                      <th>Time Left</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <td><div id="pending_loans"><p>Loading..</p></div></td>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>                  
          <!-- Pending Loans -->
       </div>
    </div>
  <!-- End Content -->
</div>
```

As of right now when I load the page, the view loads instantly however I don't see the json being rendered inside the pending loans div. In addition, if I did receive the json with a list of records, how would I iterate over them and populate the table properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [jQuery ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method to execute the AJAX call when the page loads.

Also is useful to see what is going on during script execution with console methods (webkit and ff) `console.log()` and `console.debug()` .

Wrap your AJAX call like this:

```
$(function() {
 console.log('DOM ready!');
 // show a preloader or something
 $.ajax({
    url: "/pull_pending_loans",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
      // evaluate results, or generate the table with JSON data
      console.log('Got the result',html);
      $("#pending_loans").append(html);
      // hide preloader
    }
  });
});
```

Sending HTML from ruby is not a good idea, you better return a JSON collection and use a front end framework for templating to generate the table.
Take a look at [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: This definately puts me in the right direction. One question I have is how would I use rails helpers with this solution. For example, I need to use number_to_current and link_to with some of the fields coming in from the JSON array.

Comment: I would use those helpers to perform the transformations before returning the JSON object (at lender_account#pending_loan). Other possibility is to translate those to use them with Handlebars.